# Unable to repair data volume

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility

I'm trying to repair my "Macintosh HD - Data" volume and I'm getting these errors. Is there any way to find out which files the id objects refer to so I can copy them back from a time machine backup?

I noticed that my time machine backups have been failing (they get part way through and then stop) so I did disk first aid and realized my disk has problems. I think that may be the reason for the time machine failure. Yes, I could restore from the last correct time machine, but (1) I'm not sure it is reliable if this has been an issue for some time and (2) it is over a month old (I only just realized they were failing).

Any ideas? The errors are listed below.

```
   Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 61802749.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the encryption key structures.
** Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s2.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
   The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by diskmanagementd (1412.141.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2142.81.1).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the document ID tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
error: dstream (id 267276649) does not have an associated dstream id object
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 275375703) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 275376350) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 275379570) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 275715985) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 275716339) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 277121479) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 283642448) is less than expected (2)
error: dstream (id 284123532) does not have an associated dstream id object
error: alloced_size (57344) of dstream (id 284123532) does not match calculated size (0)
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 284165078) is less than expected (2)
error: refcnt (3) of dstream id object (id 286535979) is less than expected (4)
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Verifying volume object map space.
** The volume /dev/rdisk1s2 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
** Verifying allocated space.
** Performing deferred repairs.
error: Unable to perform deferred repairs without full space verification
error: Try running fsck against the entire APFS container instead of a volume
** The volume /dev/rdisk1s2 could not be verified completely.
```

Comment: Did you run the repair against the entire container, as mentioned? If in any doubt, you should then additionally run it against the entire drive.

Comment: I'll give it a go. I was following Apple's directions of "Repair volumes, then containers, then disks" from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210898.